# How to add space to a <br> tag

Tags: html, css

I have many `<br />` tag within a main `<p>` tag.

I would like increase the visual space created by the `<br>` (example margin top and bottom).

```
<p>
Some text here<br />
Some other text<br />
Some other text
</p>
```

I could use different `<p>` but I have to do it in this way in my website.

Any idea how increase the space created by `<br>`? Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [line-height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp) property of CSS.

Example:

```
p { line-height: 90%; }
```

Comment: sorry guys but I need the space created before and after only the <br> and not for every line in the <p>.. any idea?

Comment: Wrap the lines you want with a span or something and apply the line-height to that.

Answer (score 1):

If you no want to use css, try of this code. when you use style with

of Html file the javascript programming will be prefer your order in Html file instead of same class inside the file of css.

```html
<p style="line-height: 2.7">
Some text here<br />
Some other text<br />
Some other text
</p>

<p style="margin-top: 3.5em">
Some text here<br />
Some other text<br />
Some other text
</p>

<p style="line-height: 0.6; margin-top: 7.0em">
Some text here<br />
Some other text<br />
Some other text
</p>
```

I hope my answer helped for your question.

best regards,

Wahab

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `line-height` property.

```
p {line-height:70px}
```

Comment: the space should be created before and after only the <br> and not for every line in the <p>.. could you hemp on this= thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think br tags are for line breaks nothing more nothing less. Why try to write a work-around-ish kinda code. If you can't go with any suggested answers i would say just use multiple br tags.